# Creating an ember application off a path

Tags: ember.js

I've been working with Ember (RC1) a bit - and I can create apps that load from the root of a website (foo.com/), but now I'm trying to delay loading an app until I hit a given path within my website (foo.com/app), as opposed to loading it at the root.

That "app" page is served up from the server with a div that ties to my router's root element.  The root of my app should display my applicationView and related template.

I think I'm doing everything correctly, and am not getting errors, but the only thing I see within the div where I expect my app to show is:

`<div id="ember247" class="ember-view"></div>`

At this point, my template should only show some raw html, but i'm getting nothing! Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Could you be more specific / provide code samples from your router + html page?

Comment: I found out my issue... I'm using handlebars-assets and needed to use hbs as my handlebar template extension... not handlebars :(